# how to get results on specific id from other table when i have no matching columns

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch the result values of other result1 on other result2 which print these values on other result2 using alias on specific ids of other result2 and i have no matching columns.please give me a complete solution with query if no matching columns and also give me a complete solution of matching columns with query if I have in case and below I defined two queries can anyone merge these results to get my result as I want. please give me a complete solution.

Result of 1st Query:

```
+----+----------+------------------------+
| id |asset_name| SUM(fi.`asset_amount`) |
+----+----------+------------------------+
|1383| NJHPC    |       1775091250       |
+----+----------+------------------------+
+----+----------+------------------------+
|1350| WAPDA-III|        351697500       |
+----+----------+------------------------+
```

Result of 2nd Query

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  |account_title|
+-----+-------------+
|17683|Wapda Sukuk  |
+-----+-------------+
+-----+-------------+
|17686|Neelum jhelum|        
+-----+-------------+
+-----+-------------+
|17689|Changa Manga |
+-----+-------------+
```

I want result Like this by combining both Queries.

```
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
| id  |account_title| SUM(fi.`asset_amount`) |
+-----+-------------+----------+-------------+
|17683|Wapda Sukuk  |       351697500        |
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
|17686|Neelum jhelum|     1775091250         |
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
|17689|Changa Manga |             0          |
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
```

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT c1.`id`,fi.`asset_name`,SUM(fi.`asset_amount`) FROM pms.`transfer_pool` tp 
 INNER JOIN pms.`transfer_pool_customers` c1
 ON tp.`id`=c1.`transfer_pool_id` AND tp.`transfer_status`='ACTIVE' AND tp.`checker_user_id` IS NOT NULL
  INNER JOIN pms.`transfer_pool_fi_detail` fi
  ON fi.`transfer_pool_id`=tp.`id`
    INNER JOIN pms.`product` p1 ON p1.`line`=410 AND
    tp.`product_id`=p1.`id`
     GROUP BY fi.`asset_name`,tp.`to_pool_id`;

SELECT c.id,c.`account_title`,c.`key_category_id`,c.`amount_lcy` FROM pms.`product` p 
INNER JOIN pms.`key_category` kc
 ON kc.`product_id`=p.`id`
 INNER JOIN pms.`key_category_customers` c
 ON kc.`id`=c.`key_category_id` AND p.`line`=410;
```

I want These Results how to get These Results as shown below:

```
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
| id  |account_title| SUM(fi.`asset_amount`) |
+-----+-------------+----------+-------------+
|17683|Wapda Sukuk  |       351697500        |
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
|17686|Neelum jhelum|     1775091250         |
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
|17689|Changa Manga |             0          |
+-----+-------------+------------------------+
```

I want actual output print "SUM(fi.`asset_amount`)" this column values on specific ids of 2nd query like id:17683 and id:17686

Comment: I tried to clean up the formatting but I had to guess how these different blobs fit together. Please clarify what exactly you need help with and how they are related.

Comment: you could clarify this question by adding sample data from your source tables as text to the question.

Comment: sir I already added a sample data of my table